# Django ForeignKey to AbstractBaseUser

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to set up an app that will handle reviews about registered users. So in my Review model, I want to have a ForeignKey to my User model.

I'm using a custom user profile that looks like this:

```
#In /profiles/models.py
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    company = models.CharField(default="", max_length=200)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['company']
```

I have included it with settings.py AUTH_USER_MODEL = "profiles.MyUser". It works fine with registration, creating users etc. So I know its working.

In my review model I write the following:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    reviewer = models.ForeignKey(Reviewer)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    review = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Instead of settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL I have also tried writing profiles.MyUser, 'profiles.MyUser' and MyUser.

I can successfully use the `python manage.py makemigrations reviews` command. But when I do `python manage.py migrate` I get errors no matter what version I use above.

The error I get is the following:

```
ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field reviews.Review.company: profiles.MyUser
```

Comment: Is your profiles app included in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes. The user class is working great when it comes to registering users etc.

Comment: You might need to add the initial profiles migration as a dependency to the reviews one.

Comment: Is it possible, that your database was migrated before you added the custom AUTH_USER_MODEL? If so I suggest that you drop the database, delete all existing migrations and start from scratch (run makemigrations again and migrate your database).

Comment: Correct nejc92. Solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nejc92 comment was correct. I had migrated my database earlier before I set AUTH_USER_MODEL for the first time.

I removed my whole database and created new migrations for all apps and migrated everything again from scratch. It then worked.

Sounds like a bug(?) to me.